# How to use communication between ViewModels in WPF Catel framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, catel

When I click to register button (for example) in RegistrationViewModel or any other ViewModel, I would like to change the **LeftSlide** and **MainSlide** properties in MainWindowViewModel 
 
**LeftSlide = _leftSlides[0]; 

MainSlide = any other ViewModel;** 
 
I've read this documentation, but i can't implement this in my code
https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/MVVM+communication+styles
How can i do this? Help me please

MainWindow.xaml

```c#
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Grid Width="120" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding LeftSlide,
            Converter={StaticResource ViewModelToViewConverter}}"></ContentControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding MainSlide,
            Converter={StaticResource ViewModelToViewConverter}}"></ContentControl>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

RegistrationViewModel.cs

```c#
public class RegistrationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public RegistrationViewModel()
    {
        RegistrationUserCommand = new Command(OnRegistrationUserCommandExecute);
    }

    public Command RegistrationUserCommand { get; private set; }
    private void OnRegistrationUserCommandExecute()
    {

        //when I click this button, I need to change LeftSlide property in
        // MainWindowViewModel to _leftSlides[1]  (LeftSlide = _leftSlides[1];)
         //for example
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```c#
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<IViewModel> _leftSlides;
    private List<IViewModel> _mainSlides;
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _leftSlides = new List<IViewModel>
        {
            new NavViewModel(),
            new AnotherNavViewModel()
            //another ViewModels
        };

        _mainSlides = new List<IViewModel>
        {
            new RegistrationViewModel()
            //another ViewModels
        };

        //Default ViewModels
        MainSlide = _mainSlides[0];
        LeftSlide = _leftSlides[0];
    }

    public IViewModel LeftSlide { get; set; }
    public IViewModel MainSlide { get; set; }
}
```

I haven't any experience with WPF and Catel. It's our first project with my team. We are studying.  And we can't stop using Catel Framework.

Comment: Don't handle nested user controls yourself. Let Catel take care of that. See https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Introduction+to+the+nested+user+controls+problem

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try

Comment: @GeertvanHorrik Do you have fool example or maybe any other example?

Comment: We have lots of samples with Catel, e.g. https://github.com/Catel/Catel.Examples, https://github.com/wildgums (all Catel) and an app (https://github.com/WildGums/LogViewer)

Comment: Do you find good example and solution for communication problem, and if you do can you share the solution, because I have the same problem and really don't understand the solution

Comment: We use MessageMediator to solve this problem